# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 18 out of bounds for length 18

Tags: java, bufferedreader

```
class CSVFileParser {
    ArrayList<String[]> convertCSVToArrayList(String filePath) {
        String line = "";
        ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] row = line.split(",");
                rows.add(row);
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rows;
    }
}
```

Please help me why its not working. When i try to add 18th index this error come, till 17th its working fine, anyone fix this for me, where I am doing mistake

[delivery.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18gxnHRaFujUjun9i76AQfsVaKxuheT59/view?usp=share_link)
[matches.csv file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YVarYi2qWGxp5hVqsmGQVzCRiAPNg5Cq/view?usp=share_link)

Comment: the indexing starts from 0 and for collection that have 18 items in it the length will be 18 but that index of last item will be 17, starting from 0

Comment: Which of the two files is giving you an error? Please post a [example], not a de-contextualized method with two different input files. Chances are the problem is not even in the piece of code you posted.

Comment: that delivery file gives me error when i am trying to access it

Comment: are you sure the error is in posted code? I see no indexed access

Comment: And the first file has 21 columns in the header but most rows have 18 columns filled and (coincidence?) the error is trying to access the 19th  value... BTW (or not) the one-argument `split` will ignore all empty *cells* at the end of the input string, not appropriate for reading CSV-files/tables

Comment: `line.split(",")` is a completely inappropriate way to parse a CSV file. CSV files can have embedded commas inside double-quoted strings, escaped double quotes inside them, even line breaks inside them. Use a proper CSV library like Apache Commons CSV. Parsing CSV files yourself is one of those things programmers always think they can just throw together and it always ends in tears.

Comment: Here is the [CSV file standard, RFC 4180](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180), if you want to implement it, but why would you when Apache Commons has already done it for you?

Answer (score 1):

The comments have the answer, but they're not exactly coherent.

`String.split(",", limit)` will return an array with length equal to the number of fields found up to `limit` (corrected based on a comment below), so if there are 17 commas, it will be an array with index [0] to [17], length 18. If `limit` is 0 or omitted, any empty fields at the end will be omitted. The file delivery.csv has headers with 21 fields, but not all lines are the same length. That's the first problem, you should specify the expected limit, and all lines should have 20 commas (any short lines should have empty fields at the end like "abc,def,qrs,tuv,,,").

On the other hand, your software should also be able to deal with errors like this. If you use a package that's been developed for reading CSV files, that's probably already been done. If you want to use `split()` in this way, you have to check the length of the returned array before trying to access it.

Also you might need to validate the CSV file in other ways, it might omit fields in the middle (e.g. instead of "abc,,ghi" it might have "abc,ghi"). If that's the case, try to get a file that's formatted correctly, or you might need to encode special cases to correct these problems.

Also, make sure the file doesn't have cases like "`abc,"d,f",ghi`" or "`abc,d\,f,ghi`" which have commas in the data. CSV parsing packages can deal with those cases, it will be harder for you to add code to handle that always correctly.

Comment: "`String.split",")` will return an array with length equal to the number of fields found" is not *exactly correct* - it not return empty fields at the end of the input (e.g. `"1,2,,".split(",")` returns `String[2] { "1", "2" }` - the string has 4 fields; 3 commas; but the resulting array only 2 elements) || [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)): "*Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.*"

Comment: I just checked, it depends on the `limit` parameter which is optional. If you `split(",", 20)` you will get all fields, but if it's 0 or omitted, you're right, the trailing ones will be omitted. That could be the source of the original problem.

Comment: BTW speaking of "*not exactly coherent.*", that file has 21 columns in the header (A - U), not 20 ... just saying :-/

Comment: Okay, adding another correction...